# Past paticiple or Simple past

Tags: past-tense, past-participles

Please clarify the category that "used" belongs in the sentence below.

*It is **used** for cold places.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is the lexical component of a passive construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the passive voice, and the tense is the simple present.

Here is how the same thing can be expressed in the active and passive voices:

> *You **use** it for cold places.* (active voice)
>
> *It **is used** for cold places.* (passive voice)